# Completion of stabilization versus...?

Tags: ct.category-theory

There is a passage in HA.1.4.1 which sound totally obscure to me:

[image]

This "formal argument" should look like the following equivalence:
$$
\text{Ind-}\Big( \varinjlim\big\{ C\xrightarrow{F}C\xrightarrow{F}C\xrightarrow{F}\cdots\} \Big)\cong \varprojlim\big\{\text{Ind-}(C)\xleftarrow{\text{Ind-}G}\text{Ind-}(C)\xleftarrow{\text{Ind-}G}\cdots \}$$
where $F\dashv G$ is a given adjunction, and "Ind" the functor which gives the indization of a category.

I'm not able to prove it, neither I'm sure it is something sensible in this generality.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: It smells of Gabriel–Ulmer duality. In the 1-categorical case you can think of $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ as the category of flat functors $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$, at least when $\mathcal{C}$ is small.